# If I have a function that write pictures in a thumb - How can I get the picture number for use to onclick

Tags: javascript

If I have a function that write pictures in a thumb.
How can I get the picture number for use to onclick to show the BigPic?
Only using js and html

```
<script>
var MinPixNr=100;
var MaxPixNr=115;
var title='Sofie';
var Nr=100;

//make the thumb album
  for (MinPixNr=100;MinPixNr<=115;MinPixNr++) {
document.write('<img onclick="ShowBigPic()" src="images/thumb/'+title+''+MinPixNr+'.jpg.">');
}

function ShowBigPic()
{
element=document.getElementById('BigPic');   
element.src="images/large/'+title+'"+help+".jpg";//help: i need the pic-number from the thumb
}
</script>



<body>

<script>
document.write('<br><hr><br>');

document.write('<IMG src="images/large/'+title+''+Nr+'.jpg" id="BigPic" >');

</script>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Send the name of the image with the function call:

```
document.write('<img onclick="ShowBigPic('+MinPixNr+')"

function ShowBigPic(MinPixNr)
```

Edited as per comment.

Comment: should be `"ShowBigPic('+MinPixNr+')"` otherwise all the images will pass whatever value `MinPixNr` was set to last.